# FLASK, one html with long input forms into two or more divided htmls

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using SqlAlchemy and FLASK to build a web interface that contains more than 50 user input fields. All the data should enter the database at the same time. Currently every input fields are in one html page(you have to scroll down pretty hard), to minimize this scrolling and for better compartmentalization, I would like to divide this one long html into two or more separate htmls. So when user completes filling in the input fields for page 1, I would like for them to click 'next' button to go to page 2 and so on. Since the data needs to go into the database all at once, I want to keep only one 'submit' button.

I was looking over the web regarding this matter but I wasn't sure what to search for.

Any idea or link to documentations will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please follow the link for pagination http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/44/ if you don't want to use javascript to create views.